# :nth-child in combination with :not

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Is there a possibility to select like every second item that does not have a specific class with plain CSS?

Like this:

```
li:not(.hidden):nth-child(2n) {
    background: gray;
}
```

The main reason is to select every second element of a one-dimensional list that also contains hidden elements. If I would simply do `li:nth-child(2n)` then even the hidden elements would be selected as well.

Comment: Can post your html?

Comment: This seems to work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/d24j85f1/1/

Comment: If you are talking about ignoring the .hidden in the iteration, no, you can't do it.